# Why is MySQL server only accepting empty passwords?

Tags: mysql

I've added a new user to my MySQL 5.1 server on a fresh installation of Fedora 13 and set its password. (Using `SET PASSWORD FOR USER myuser = PASSWORD('...')`), but MySQL only accepts the user when I'm using an empty password to log on.

In other words: When I enter the correct password, I get an access denied error. When I use an empty string, it get in.

Things I tried:

- Changing the password and changing it back.
- Recreating the user.
- I verified that changing the password actually modifies the password hash in the user table.
- It makes no difference if I connect from the command line (`mysql -u myuser -p`) or from phpMySQL.
- I experimented with different hostnames (myuser, myuser@localhost, myuser@'%')

Is there any configuration option which might trigger this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you did not flush the privileges

```
flush privileges
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I guess if I'd just had rebooted the workstation, like I'd almost automatically do on a Windows box, it'd work, too :)